# Combining 2+ tables in ModelBuilder into just 1 supertable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

This might be a stupid question but is it possible to add multiple tables in ArcGIS Modelbuilder together? Just add 2 tables together, like a spreadsheet list without a common factor? I have been googling this for ages and all the methods seems to require some common factor?

For example:

Table 1:
x | 2
z | 5

Table 2:
a | 10
c | 13

Combined Supertable:
x | 2
z | 5
a | 10
c | 13

Comment: My dummy table failed, I tried to make it vertical but it got converted to horizontal.

Comment: Okay so I am almost done with my model. Currently I have 13 different tables as final output. Now I only need to merge all of them into 1 table (as I previosly asked about). Is this not possible in ArcGIS modelbuilder? Should I look into different methods, such as excel functions and/or python script?

Answer (score 1):

Create an arbitrary common factor in each table.  For example, in each table create a column called "Merge".  Make it an integer short field.  Now open the [Calculate Field Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm).  Click the expression box and in the code block insert the code below.  In the Pre logic script code type: autoIncrement()

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
  global rec 
  pStart = 1  
  pInterval = 1 
  if (rec == 0):  
    rec = pStart  
  else:  
    rec += pInterval  
  return rec
```

You could put this calculate field tool into your model, one for each table.  Now, you could then use the Merge Tool and use this common arbitrary field.  The code I gave you will populate the field in each table with incremental values in each row.

Without seeing your model, this is my first suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yeah I was thinking about doing something along those lines, however 1 issue is the fact that not all of these tables that Im merging have the same columns. However I would still like to have the various tables stacked if possible. Hence I think this approach would bombard me with cells with "Null" values. Thoughts?

Comment: You say "the same columns", but do you mean the same number of columns?