# Using Merge in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I have about 2 massive layer files with polygons and like 10 layer files with points that I would like to "Merge" together separately (polygons in one and points in another) but for some reason It removes my firs column with important ID's and replace it with randomly generated ObjID? How can I prevent this from happening? Another problem that I found was that everytime I tried to marge the 2 massive layers with points it finished the merging prosess but when I look at the data in the attribute table it always stopped at like 6025 or something. I think it should be more like ca 10000.

I want to do this as I currently have multiple layer files that I want to run through both "generate near table" and "make feature layer". The issue is that "make feature layer" can only do 1 layer. Hence I thought It might work if I can just have all the polygons layers as 1 superlayer and all the points as another super layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first column is an automatic ID field. If for some reason you need to preserve the specific ID value for each row, you need to create a new column and populate it with the ID values. Merging two layers will definitely change the automatic ID for all the features of one of them (usually, retains the add order in the merge tool box).

As for your point data, The attribute field sometimes does not show all the rows for large datasets (though 10000 isn't that large). at the bottom of the attribute table you should see a row count value, check if that fits the supposed number of points, if not, make sure you actually have ~10000 points in those 10 layers.

Comment: Hi HDunn
Thanks for quick reply, highly appreciated!
Alright, I see. Is there a tool in Modelbuilder to automate this?
I did actually think about doing something like that but this is not a one time analysis. Hence the layers are connected to a PostGIS database thats constantly getting updated. I guess this goes back to my 3rd question that I posted here yesterday about a tool to copy all the data from one spreadsheet to another qithout having a common factor. Do you know if thats possible? 


Thanks

Comment: Heres my question; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189239/combining-2-tables-in-modelbuilder-into-just-1-supertable